# Google`s Chrome won't reopen prior windows with "continue where I left off" checked

Tags: google-chrome

Recently chrome stopped reopening the windows/tabs from it previous sessions.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Cloud printing maybe the culprit.

Disable in in Cloud print...

To disable "Cloud Print"

```
Open "Settings" from Google wrench icon...
- Make sure Setting is selected on left panel , not history or extensions. &c
- - Select "Show advanced settings" at bottom of window if shown...
- - - Near at at the bottom click in "Disable Google Cloud ..."
- - - - Some have reported Background apps/  Continue running...  Should also be unchecked
```